# Multi Site Network Admin

Tags: network-admin

I am currently unable to access the dashboard or any of the items in the Network admin section ( example URL http://www.example.com/wp-admin/network/plugins.php)

"I get a Google error that says This page isn't working.
www.example.com redirected you too many times

Try Clearing your cookies.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

The sites work fine and the individual site admins work fine, but I can't get to the network piece to do updates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and reactivated them 1 by 1 to identify which is responsible? What did you change/do that triggered the problem? Did you recently do a migration? At the moment there's not enough information to answer, and nothing that points to a cause

Answer (score 0):

Check your htaccess file, which might be causing problems. Mine looks like this (it forces SSL and adds the www part if needed):

```
#force everything to https

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]



# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You might also consider what you changed lately. Perhaps a new plugin, or some code in your (child) theme. Revert to one of the 'twenty' themes to check theme problems. Rename the plugins folder temporarily to remove possible plugin problems.

Finally, check the wp_options tables for the correct site URL. There's lots of them in there (one for each sub-site), but the first one on the list might be the one for the main site.